# Assembly - Debug.exe - Will altering data through debug cause the os/apps to fail?

Tags: assembly

I am beginning to learn assembly language.  I just wanted one thing clarified:

Will altering data through debug cause my os/apps to fail?

I have run debug through cmd and done the E command

```
E 100
```

Here I use `space` to see what's stored in the memory at these locations:

```
0B79:0100 BE.  90.   02.    ... etc
```

Will overwriting these memory spaces cause errors in the currently running system?

When starting up, Debug allocates 65k bytes of memory as a workspace and first 100 bytes is PSP.  My question is probably more directly this:

Is the workspace that I'm looking at unallocated memory, or memory in use by os / applications.

Once again please pardon my newbie'ness, that is after all what I am in relation to assembly language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a 64 KB unallocated memory segment.
With debug we can simple build a *.com application, but normaly not a *.exe.

With using an assembler we can build *.exe applications.
Within a *.exe we can reserve in a solid form one code segment, one data segment and one stack segment.
If a DOS aplication is starting, then DOS give all of the free memory to the application, but we do not know how many memmory-segments are free and on wich address.
For to allocate more memmory we can free up all the unused memmory in the first step and in the second step we can allocate more memmory.

```
SETFREE:  mov     bx, ss   ; Using for *.exe:
          mov     ax, es   ; calculating the number of paragraps from
          sub     bx, ax   ; the PSP to the beginning of the stack
          mov     ax, sp   ; + adding the length of the stack
          add     ax, 0Fh
          shr     ax, 4
          add     bx, ax
          mov     ah, 4Ah
          int   21h
          ret
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GETSPACE: mov     ah, 48h ; BX = number of paragraphs
          int   21h
          ret             ; Return: AX = segment
```

RBIL->inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.G

```
--------D-2148-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - ALLOCATE MEMORY
AH = 48h
BX = number of paragraphs to allocate
Return: CF clear if successful
    AX = segment of allocated block
CF set on error
    AX = error code (07h,08h) (see #01680 at AH=59h/BX=0000h)
    BX = size of largest available block
Notes:  DOS 2.1-6.0 coalesces free blocks while scanning for a block to
  allocate
.COM programs are initially allocated the largest available memory
  block, and should free some memory with AH=49h before attempting any
  allocations
under the FlashTek X-32 DOS extender, EBX contains a protected-mode
  near pointer to the allocated block on a successful return
SeeAlso: AH=49h,AH=4Ah,AH=58h,AH=83h

--------D-2149-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - FREE MEMORY
AH = 49h
ES = segment of block to free
Return: CF clear if successful
CF set on error
    AX = error code (07h,09h) (see #01680 at AH=59h/BX=0000h)
Notes:  apparently never returns an error 07h, despite official docs; DOS 2.1+
code contains only an error 09h exit
DOS 2.1-6.0 does not coalesce adjacent free blocks when a block is
freed, only when a block is allocated or resized
the code for this function is identical in DOS 2.1-6.0 except for
calls to start/end a critical section in DOS 3.0+
SeeAlso: AH=48h,AH=4Ah

--------D-214A-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - RESIZE MEMORY BLOCK
AH = 4Ah
BX = new size in paragraphs
ES = segment of block to resize
Return: CF clear if successful
 CF set on error
    AX = error code (07h,08h,09h) (see #01680 at AH=59h/BX=0000h)
    BX = maximum paragraphs available for specified memory block
Notes:  under DOS 2.1-6.0, if there is insufficient memory to expand the block
as much as requested, the block will be made as large as possible
DOS 2.1-6.0 coalesces any free blocks immediately following the block
to be resized
SeeAlso: AH=48h,AH=49h,AH=83h
```